# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT Keeps Popping Up

Tags: swift

I am currently programming an app in XCode using Swift, and I need a countdown. This is the code I'm using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
var count = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {
    if (count > 0) {
        timeLabel.text = String(count--)
    }
}
```

This is the error message I keep getting:

> 2015-08-06 15:39:31.741 Odd One Out[15315:2026404] Unknown class ArcadeViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   2015-08-06 15:39:31.767 Odd One Out[15315:2026404] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scoreLabel.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting all outlets, but it still keeps showing Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT. Does anyone know what may be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: In the connections inspector make sure a connection isn't listed that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: If you carefully read the error message, you'll see that it contains specific details regarding the nature of the problem, and that the actual problem has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Selector is wrong.

```
Selector("updateTimer")
```

Also, that kind of errors are due to bad connections between Storyboard elements and inexistent objects.

For example, ctrl-drag connecting (Outlet) and then deleting the line of code where the Outlet was defined causes this issue, because the Storyboard is still configured to use that ivar. Changing the ivar name does that too.

For the Unknown Class error, do you have a class named `ArcadeViewController` (I mean: the .swift file and also the interface defined in it?).